# onkeypress="" affects other fields. How to restrict?

Tags: javascript, inputfield, inputtext

This is my page:

---

[image]

---

and to simplify the search my apex:inputText defines: `onkeypress="return searchOnEnter(event);"`

```
function searchOnEnter(event)  {
    if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
        return search();
    }
    return true;
}
```

But as soon as I press enter on any other apex:inputField like this one:

---

[image]

---

It triggers my `searchOnEnter()` function.
Why does this even happen, that's not what I expected!

Is there any way to avoid this and restrict the function to only trigger on the search field?

Comment: check may be you are calling searchOnEnter() this function from anywhere else also.

Comment: @patelkiran3090 I checked it, nowhere else.

Comment: can u add here your code? this should not happen so need to check code if any problem in that.

Comment: thanks for asking further questions @patelkiran3090! this made me thinking of finding the problem somewhere else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that I am not using the `action="{!doSearch}"` attribute on the button. Instead I defined the `onClick="return search();"` attribute.
This leads to submitting the whole form, for any enter press in my form fields.

instead I am now using `onmousedown="return search();"`
this ensures the event to be a real mousedown (real click).

```
<apex:inputText id="searchValue" value="{!searchValue}" onkeypress="return searchOnEnter(event);" />
<apex:commandButton value="Search" onmousedown="return search();" />
```

Thanks for asking further questions @patelkiran3090!

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, please accept your own answer, so others don't think the question is unanswered.